# VSTS dotnet restore command fails to get nuget package

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, nuget-package-restore

I have been successfully running a build definition against a dotnet core web application for months now but the build has started to fail. The error occurs when trying to run a dotnet restore command on my projects.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3gyX.png

I am getting the following error when the restore task runs:

```
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-
  flatcontainer/netcore.mailkit/index.json'.
  Response status code does not indicate success: 504 (Gateway Timeout).
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-
  flatcontainer/netcore.mailkit/index.json'.
  Response status code does not indicate success: 504 (Gateway Timeout).
```

I have manually run the dotnet restore command on my local machine and do not get the error.

Has anyone experienced something like this before in VSTS?

Thanks

Comment: Did you link the image VSTS Build Definition correctly, it can not be reached?

Comment: The image uploads but only produced the image text. I have added a direct link to the image instead.

Comment: Can you also show the detail build logs?

Comment: This looks like its a Microsoft issue.https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsoservice/?p=15195

Comment: So did you solve your problem as the link mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it was a Microsoft issue.

http://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsoservice/?p=15195

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/129183/getting-504-gateway-timeout-on-hosted-vs2017-agent.html

Comment: You can mark it as answer. And it will also benefit others who have similar questions.